# Is there a way to "lock" some cells in a notebook?

Tags: notebooks

Is there a way to "lock" some cells in a notebook so they can't be edited? It's usually input cell that's documenting some functionality.  I'd like other readers of the notebook to be able to execute them but not changing them.

Comment: You've seen [`Editable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Editable.html) already?

Comment: How to resolve it?  Can it be resolved without being deleted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to make some cell non editable, mark these cells and use the menu entry

Cell -> CellProperties

and remove the mark before `Editable`.

If your cell is an Input-Cell, it can be evaluated but not edited.

Comment: For extra protection, _before_ making the cell not `Editable`, you may wish to make it not `Deletable`. To do so, select the cell, open the Option Inspector, and uncheck `Deletable` in the `Cell Options > General Properties` section. (And while you're there you can then also uncheck `Editable`.)

Comment: @murray, nice tip. I wasn't aware of the `Deletable` option.

Comment: And as I learned when I first tried it, you must make a cell non-`Deletable` _before_ you make it non-`Editable`!

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you have an open notebook, say "Untitled-1". The following code, executed in the same notebook or another, will select all the Input cells and set them to un-Editable and un-Evaluatable.

```
nb = First[Notebooks["Untitled-1"]];
inputCells = NotebookFind[nb,
  "Input", All, CellStyle];
SetOptions[inputCells, 
  Evaluatable -> False,
  Editable -> False]
```